# Can't log into Ubuntu 14.04 Samba share via Windows 7

Tags: 14.04, windows-7, samba

I'm sorry to ask what seems to be such a popular, over-asked question but I've done my digging and can't, for the life of me, log into my Ubuntu 14.04 samba share with Windows 7. Here's my smb.conf file:

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
server string = Samba Server %v
netbios name = ubuntu
security = user
map to guest = bad user
name resolve order = bcast host
dns proxy = no

[backup]
path = /media/Backup
valid users = @securedgroup
browsable =yes
guest ok = no
writable = yes
read only = no
```

**UBUNTU SIDE**

- My ext4 software raid array is mounted on /media/Backup.
- My main user belongs to the "securedgroup" group.
- I have added my main user to the smb user list and set a smb password.
- /media/Backup is set to home:securedgroup and is drwxr-xr-x
- After every change I make sure to restart the smb service.

Here is the output of "testparm":

```
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
Processing section "[backup]"
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE
Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions

[global]
        server string = Samba Server %v
        map to guest = Bad User
        name resolve order = bcast, host
        dns proxy = No
        idmap config * : backend = tdb

[backup]
        path = /media/Backup
        valid users = @securedgroup
        read only = No
```

**WINDOWS SIDE**

- I can see my server on the network from Windows.
- I can not connect to  it no matter what I try logging in with, which should just be my smb username and password.
- I'm not sure what my settings where at the time, but at one point I was getting "Access Denied" instead of invalid username/password.
- At another point, I was actually seeing the Backup directory but couldn't log into it, same as now (only now it has me logging into the Ubuntu server)

Fun fact: It was working under a guest account, but I wanted to secure it. Since then, I haven't been able to access it... Silly me.

I've tinkered around with various samba options, such as wins support, but still have had no luck.

So far, not impressed with samba.

Comment: So I'm not alone in this dark world, where I have to allow guest-write access in order to edit a project from Windows.